# conditional formatting on HTML table

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML table

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr bgcolor="#6699FF">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>DOJ</th>
    <th>BAU</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>XXX</td>
    <<td>2015-06-03</td>
      <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>YYY</td>
    <<td>2015-05-03</td>
      <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ZZZ</td>
    <<td>2015-04-03</td>
      <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

` My requirement is if BAU (3rd column) is 1, then the corresponding DOJ (2nd column) cell will be in green color and so on. Im generating this report in linux. Is there any way to do this using CSS and HTML only. If not what is the other way?? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can either produce what you want server side or use JavaScript. There's no conditionals in neither HTML or CSS

Comment: It is just a some report i'm generating in LINUX using BTEQ to get data from the database and converting them into a HTML table and i want to format it as mentioned above. If we can use Java script, how to do so??

Answer (score 5):

There is one way.

You can use `data-*` attributes.

Like this:

```
<!-- ... -->

<tr bgcolor="#6699FF">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>DOJ</th>
    <th>BAU</th>
</tr>
<tr data-bau="1">
    <td>XXX</td>
    <td>2015-06-03</td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>

<!-- ... -->
```

Then, on your CSS:

```
table tr[data-bau="1"] td:first-child + td {background:lightgreen;}
table tr[data-bau="2"] td:first-child + td {background:lightblue;}
table tr[data-bau="3"] td:first-child + td {background:lightyellow;}
/* ... */
```

---

Example:

```css
table tr[data-bau="1"] td:first-child + td {background:lightgreen;}
table tr[data-bau="2"] td:first-child + td {background:lightblue;}
table tr[data-bau="3"] td:first-child + td {background:lightyellow;}
```

```html
<table border="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#6699FF">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>DOJ</th>
  <th>BAU</th>
 </tr>
 <tr data-bau="1">
  <td>XXX</td>
  <td>2015-06-03</td>
  <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr data-bau="2">
  <td>YYY</td>
  <td>2015-05-03</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr data-bau="3">
  <td>ZZZ</td>
  <td>2015-04-03</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

---

If this is not an option, you can use the `style` attribute, when you generate the HTML:

```html
<table border="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#6699FF">
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>DOJ</th>
  <th>BAU</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>XXX</td>
  <td style="background: lightgreen;">2015-06-03</td>
  <td>1</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>YYY</td>
  <td style="background: lightblue;">2015-05-03</td>
  <td>2</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>ZZZ</td>
  <td style="background: lightyellow;">2015-04-03</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man! but we can't predict the bau value, it may be anything. In that case, is there any thing like getting parameter and passing it to data-bau??

Comment: @Hasain You can put any value inside `data-bau`, as long as you put the same values on your CSS. But, for you to set colors, you must knows what BAU will have what color. Once you have that list, you can easily build the CSS. The other alternatives, include sending the background color already in the `td` or adding a bunch of classes with the BAU value (also requires knowing the value range).

Comment: Thanks again Ismael. What I'm trying to say is, this HTML is going to get generated by automated shell script and the same will be sent to me, i want to do this formatting before sending mail all by itself

Comment: @Hasain If you are going to send by email, your best bet and hope is inline styles. **IF YOU ARE REALLY LUCKY** your styles may not be deleted. Most email clients delete all `<style>` tags. Your only option is **REALLY** inline styles (using the attribute `style`).

Comment: Appreciate your help. since i'm new to web page developing would you mind giving a code snippet??

Comment: @Hasain What snippet you want?

Comment: HTML code snippet using style attribute, to satisfy my condition.

Comment: can u also tell, how to select the second column from the last, in the HTML table contains 5 column. Thank you

Comment: @Hasain That's impossible with CSS. As far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't.

Neither CSS or HTML provide any means to format based on the value of text nodes.

You need a programming language to do this. You should probably use whatever programming language you are writing your Linux application in and add it as a feature of that application.

Comment: It is just a some report i'm generating in LINUX using BTEQ to get data from the database and converting them into a HTML table and i want to format it as mentioned above. If we can use Java script, how to do so??